# Javascript control of iFrame page transitions

Tags: javascript, iframe

Firstly I am a complete novice so please respond accordingly ...

I have managed to create an iframe with three html pages dynamically loading in sequence every 1500ms (www.online95.com/agency.html)

On each of the html pages being loaded into the iframe (/budget,html, voluntary.html and robust.html) I have added a row of circles (white=off and red=on) which if clicked load the corresponding page into the iframe

The problem is that the original script isn't linked with the individual html pages so that the original sequence continues to load every 1500ms regardless of which page you have manually loaded into the iframe or when you loaded it

I'm looking for some script to rest variables in the original javascript on /agency.html so that the next dymanic page load will be the one after the page manually loaded and rest the timer to

Also I would like to be able to add a pause button

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, I have to say this is a really bad practice, you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and a [jQuery Slider Plugin](http://basic-slider.com/), it will be more effective.

doing what you want is beeing more complicated with iframes, but you can do it. you should use iframe onload event for changing current page index(i),

here is how you can do,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var pages=new Array();
       pages[0]="/budget.html";
       pages[1]="/voluntary.html";
       pages[2]="/robust.html";

 var i=0;
 var time=4000; // this is set in milliseconds
 var timer = false;
 var timerSetter;

function pageChange() {
 document.getElementById("agencyframe").src=pages[i];
 i++;
 if(i==pages.length) {
   i=0;
 }
 timerSetter = setTimeout("pageChange()",time);
}

function contentChanged(e) {
    if (!timer)  { pageChange(); timer=true;}
    if (timerSetter) {
        clearTimeout(timerSetter);  
        timerSetter = setTimeout("pageChange()",time); 
    }
    var  newSrc = e.contentWindow.location.href;
    for (var j=0; j < pages.length; j++) {
         if (newSrc.match(pages[j])) {
            i = j+1;
            if(i==pages.length) {
               i=0;
            }
         } 
    }
}
</script>
```

And don't forget to set onload attribute for iframe,

```
<iframe id="agencyframe" onload="contentChanged(this)" src="/budget.html">
</iframe>
```

**UPDATE:**

As I understand you want to change iframe page when user click (page zero-page one-page two) [on this page.](http://www.online95.com/agency.html)

you can change location of a iframe like this,

```
document.getElementById("agencyframe").src = "/budget.html";
```

so change your function like this,

```
function pageZero() {
    document.getElementById("prin_div1").setAttribute("class", "prin_on");
    document.getElementById("prin_div2").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
    document.getElementById("prin_div3").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
    document.getElementById("agencyframe").src = pages[0];
}

function pageOne() {
    document.getElementById("prin_div1").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
    document.getElementById("prin_div2").setAttribute("class", "prin_on");
    document.getElementById("prin_div3").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
    document.getElementById("agencyframe").src = pages[1];
}

function pageTwo() {
    document.getElementById("prin_div1").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
    document.getElementById("prin_div2").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
    document.getElementById("prin_div3").setAttribute("class", "prin_on");
    document.getElementById("agencyframe").src = pages[2];
}
```

**UPDATE -2:**

Change `contentChanged` function like this,

```
function contentChanged(e) {
    if (!timer)  { pageChange(); timer=true;}
    if (timerSetter) {
        clearTimeout(timerSetter);  
        timerSetter = setTimeout("pageChange()",time); 
    }
    var  newSrc = e.contentWindow.location.href;
    for (var j=0; j < pages.length; j++) {
         if (newSrc.match(pages[j])) {
            i = j+1;
            document.getElementById("prin_div"+i).setAttribute("class", "prin_on");
            if(i==pages.length) {
               i=0;
            }
         } else {
            document.getElementById("prin_div"+(j+1)).setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I had looked at that jQuery Slider Plugin but thought it was only for images not webpages, and I can never match how the text looks when I use images. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I've notice that the onload script doesn't reset the timer, so if you manually click onto a new page after 12000ms then it will only stay on that page for 3000ms before automatically skipping to the next page. Not sure if I have copied your code incorrectly or if you code was not designed to rest the timer?

Comment: @RobWilliams, yes, you are right, it doesn't reset the timer when user click onto a new page link, I've changed it, now it's working as you want.

Comment: Many thanks that works beautifully now.  Can I ask one further question?

Comment: I have written three short scripts to change the "class" of div on the page containing the iframe. Is there any way of linking these to the ifrmae onload function and running the one corresponding to the page loaded?  function pageZero() {
 document.getElementById("prin_div1").setAttribute("class", "prin_on");
 document.getElementById("prin_div2").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
 document.getElementById("prin_div3").setAttribute("class", "prin_off");
}

Are you self employed?

Comment: @RobWilliams, look my updated answer again and don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem in stackoverflow and the others.

Comment: Sorry I haven't explained myself very clearly. The buttons on that page were simply to test the scripts to change the class of the above divs. What I would like to do is run one of these scripts when the iframe loads ... the one corresponding to the page loaded. So that the text relating to the page in the iframe will be highlighted. Hope this is a little clearer thanmy last attempt at explaining what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @RobWilliams, Ok I got it now, and appended updated `contentChanged` function in my answer below.

Comment: Thank you so very much for all your help! You patience with my lack of any knowledge, speed of response and general helpfulness has been amazing ... remarketable!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, don't have the controls on the pages which are loaded. As you have seen, scripting between different loaded pages can be very complicated and is not what scripts are really intended for.

I would keep the controls on the parent page. You can make them seem to overlay by using `position:absolute; z-index:2;` and `top/bottom: XYZpx; left/right: ABCpx;` to position them correctly (as well as the parent being `position:relative`) and correct background settings.

Then all you would need to do is store the timer in a variable (`var timer = window.setTimeout(...)`) and cancel it when the user clicks one of the controls (`controls.onclick = function(timer) { window.clearTimeout(timer); }`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did think of this but the problem them becomes how do i dynamically change the controllers to switch on/off as the pages are either dynamically loaded in sequence of directly from the controllers. At the moment I have three variations of the controllers, corresponding to the page they are displayed on

Comment: It would surely not be a big problem - the click on a controller would flip the clicked controller to the on-state (easy by CSS and just attaching a class when on); otherwise the function called by setTimeout will rotate through an array of the three controllers, loading their corresponding page and setting the controller to 'on'. This is a common problem when targeting navigation systems and you can find a lot of resources online.